# Could I have some help solving this Markov Matrix problem?

Tags: linear-algebra

Well, I've been reading over the internet but I've been unable to find a straight answer.Can someone help me?

Let
P=$$ \left[
    \begin{matrix}
    P1 \\
    P2 \\
    P3 \\
    \end{matrix}
\right]$$be a vector of sunny,cloudy,and rainy,respectively.Suppose that the probability on day Pn satisfies
Pn+1=APn,such that A=$$ \left[
    \begin{matrix}
    0.8&0.2&0.2 \\
    0.1&0.7&0.2 \\
    0.1&0.1&0.6 \\
    \end{matrix}
\right]$$
When today’s weather is sunny,i.e.,Po=$$ \left[
    \begin{matrix}
    1 \\
    0 \\
    0 \\
    \end{matrix}
\right]$$,find the value of P∞.

I have done this step, do not know what to do next
Pn=A^nPo=PΛ^nP^-1Po

=$$(V1V2...Vn) \left[ \begin{matrix}λ1\ddots&0\\0&λn\\\end{matrix}\right]P^-1Po$$

=$$ \left[
    \begin{matrix}
    2.5&0&-1 \\
    1.5&-1&1 \\
    1&1&0 \\
    \end{matrix}
\right] \left[
    \begin{matrix}
    1&0&0 \\
    0&0.5&0 \\
    0&0&0.6^n \\
    \end{matrix}
\right]\left[
    \begin{matrix}
    0.2&0.2&0.2\\
    -0.2&-0.2&0.8 \\
   -0.5&0.5&0.5 \\
    \end{matrix}
\right]\left[
    \begin{matrix}
    1\\
    0\\
    0\\
    \end{matrix}
\right]$$

Comment: Multiply it out and take the limit as $n\to\infty$  Or rather, take the limit first, and then multiply it out.

Comment: Small typo, the middle entry of the middle matrix in your last equation should be $0.5^n$

Comment: Your matrix decomposition is correct fwiw.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you might find this approach useful.  Another way to ask the question is to find the eigenvector of $A$ that corresponds to eigenvalue $\lambda=1$:

$$
AP=P
$$

In other words, you are seeking the limiting distribution $P$ such that it is stable:  Additional applications of $A$ will not change the value.  This is equivalent, I believe, to $P_{\infty}$ in your description.

The additional constraint is the sum of the values in $P$ must be equal to $1$, since it is a probability distribution.  Therefore, the final eigenvector will need to be scaled so the sum of the entries is $1$.

The unscaled eigenvector which corresponds to
$\lambda=1$ is

$$
P=
\begin{bmatrix}
0.811107 \\
0.486664 \\
0.324443 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The sum of the terms is $1.62221$, so dividing by this yields the scaled eigenvector which corresponds to $\lambda=1$ which is

$$
\hat{P}=
\begin{bmatrix}
0.5 \\
0.3 \\
0.2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
=P_{\infty}
$$

Please note:  The first eigenvector in your result that corresponds to $\lambda=1$ is $\begin{bmatrix} 2.5 \\ 1.5 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ which will also work, but would need to be rescaled by dividing by the sum of its entries (which is $5$) leading to the same final result $\begin{bmatrix}
0.5 \\
0.3 \\
0.2 \\
\end{bmatrix}$.

Also please note that this final result does not depend on the initial condition.

I hope this helps.